# How to Use Microsoft Graph C# SDK to see calendarView Between an End and Start date

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph SDK to query the calendarView endpoint. I am able to make this query using the regular `HttpClient` but for convenience reasons would like to do this through the SDK. The endpoint that I would be trying to hit with the query params looks like this:

`GET /v1.0/me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2019-01-01T00:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2019-03-01T00:00:00.0000000`

I've attempted to make the call through the Graph SDK this way:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new PreAuthorizedBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(accessToken));
var rooms = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request().Filter("start/dateTime eq '2019-01-08T20:00:00.0000000' and end/dateTime eq '2019-01-08T20:00:00.0000000'").GetAsync();
```

I am receiving a 200 for this but my response has no values in it. If I remove the end/dateTime portion I get values just for the start/dateTime day. It seems like the filter works only for specifics and not for a range. Does anyone have any hints for filtering within a range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```cs
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("startDateTime", "2019-01-01T00:00:00.0000000"),
    new QueryOption("endDateTime", "2019-03-01T00:00:00.0000000")
};

UserCalendarViewCollectionPage todaysEvents = await graphClient.Me.CalendarView.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
```

[CalendarView docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: @craigbot Could you mark the question as answered if it solved your problem? Thanks!